# Convert array of hash by logstash to simple hash

Tags: json, ruby, parsing, elasticsearch, logstash

I am trying to parse by logstash this:

```
"attributes": [
          {
            "value": "ValueA",
            "name": "NameA"
          },
          {
            "value": "ValueB",
            "name": "NameB"
          },
          {
            "value": "ValueC",
            "name": "NameC"
          }
        ],
```

To this:

```
"attributes": {
  "NameA": "ValueA",
  "NameB": "ValueB",
  "NameC": "ValueC"
}
```

Any recommendations?

I don't want to split this list to more records...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found th solution. For anyone dealing with a similar problem, here is the solution and a short story...

In the beginning, I tried this:

```
ruby {
  code => '
    xx = event.get("[path][to][data_source]")
    event.set(['_my_destination'], Hash[xx.collect { |p| [p[:name], p[:value]] }])
  '
```

But it returned an error because of the set method allowing a string only.

So I tried to do it this way:

```
ruby {
  code => '
    event.get("[path][to][data_source]").each do |item|
      k = item[:name]
      event.set("[_my_destination][#{k}]", item[:value])
    end
  '
}
```

I spent a lot of time debugging it because it works everywhere except in logstash :-D. After some grumbling, I finally fixed it. The solution with commentary is as follows.

```
ruby {
  code => '
    i = 0    # need index to address hash in array 
    event.get("[json_msg][mail][headers]").each do |item|
      # need to use event.get function to get value
      k = event.get("[json_msg][mail][headers][#{i}][name]")
      v = event.get("[json_msg][mail][headers][#{i}][value]")

      # now it is simple
      event.set("[json_msg][headers][#{k}]", v)
      i += 1
    end
  '
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be able to do it with a custom Ruby script - see the [`ruby`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-ruby.html) filter. You'll use the [Event API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/event-api.html) to manipulate the event.

Maybe the [`aggregate`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-aggregate.html) filter could be also used but the Ruby script with one for loop seems more straightforward to me.